# Not able to type "=" and "-" characters in keyboard

Tags: shortcut-keys

- When I type <kbd>=</kbd> (equal to) key in the keyboard it zooms in
- When I type <kbd>-</kbd> (minus) key it zooms out.

I have disabled all zoom shortcuts in settings but still the problem persists.

How do I remove these zoom settings so that I am able to type these characters?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your <kbd>CTRL</kbd> is pressed.

- <kbd>CTRL +</kbd> perform Zoom In
- <kbd>CTRL -</kbd> perform Zoom Out

The `=` and `+` are located on the same key in the keyboard, so when you press on `=` you actually press on `+`

Please try to release both <kbd>CTRL</kbd> by pressing on them a few times.

It might solve your problem